# Abstract class with abstract getters and setters

Tags: java

Say I have an abstract class `List` and I want to make a class that extends this class called `MyList`. Is it bad programming practice to put abstract getters and setters in the abstract class, forcing `MyList` to override them?

The reason I want to do this is something like setting a constant capacity that is different for each specialization of a `List`. So I would do something like this:

```
public abstract class List {
    public abstract int getMaximumSize();
}

public class MyList extends List {
    @Override
    public int getMaximumSize() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I also had another example where I put a setter in the abstract class but now I forget.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this is a reasonable approach (modulo setters. Don't do setters in abstract, non-abstract, or any other types of files).

One issue here though - what happens if the implementor of your class is an idiot? consider

```
public abstract class List {
    public abstract int getMaximumSize();
}

public class MyList extends List {
    @Override
    public int getMaximumSize() {
        // negative?!?!
        return -10;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid this, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class List {
    // this is the method to override
    protected abstract int getMaximumSizeInternal();
    // and this method is final. Can't mess around with that!
    public final int getMaximumSize() {
        int x = getMaximumSizeInternal();
        if (x < 0) { throw new RuntimeException ("Apologies, sub-classer is an idiot"); }
        return x;
}

public class MyList extends List {
    @Override
    protected int getMaximumSizeInternal() {
        // negative?!?!
        return -10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Fail as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would recommend an interface e.g.

```
public interface MaxList extends List // or some better name {
    public int getMaxSize();
}
```

Then for `MyList`

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList implements MaxList { 
// The above assumes you want to extend ArrayList. You may extend some other 
// List implementation or provide your own.
    @Override
    public int getMaximumSize() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am assuming you want to extend an implementation of `java.util.List`. If you do not, there is no need for `MaxList` interface to extend `java.util.List` or MyList to extends `java.util.ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok if you want to force every child to have getter\setter. Eventually, if it satisfies your needs, it is ok, I would rather ask if there is a better way to achieve this behaviour.